# How to implements border with text in RadioGroup on android (Kotlin/Java)?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I need to create a `RadioGroup` with border and text description, similar a `OutlinedBox` the Material Design.

The image representing actual design:

[image]

I create this `drawableBackground`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
    <corners android:radius="4dp" />
    <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="@color/gainsboro" />
</shape>
```

And my code is:

```
<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/radioGroupComplete"
    android:checkedButton="@id/radioButtonCompleteNo"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginHorizontal="16dp"
    android:layout_marginVertical="8dp"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="@drawable/input_border">

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioButtonCompleteYes"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/todo_form_yes"/>

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioButtonCompleteNo"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/todo_form_no"/>
</RadioGroup>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just put the RadioGroup in RelativeLayout:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/spinner_parent"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/border"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginHorizontal="10dp">

<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/radioGroupComplete"
    android:checkedButton="@id/radioButtonCompleteNo"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginHorizontal="16dp"
    android:layout_marginVertical="8dp"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    
<RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/radioButtonCompleteYes"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="@string/todo_form_yes"/>

<RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/radioButtonCompleteNo"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="@string/todo_form_no"/>
</RadioGroup>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And add border.xml in "drawable" folder:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<solid android:color="@color/white"/>
<stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="@color/black" />
<padding android:left="0dp" android:top="0dp" android:right="0dp" 
      android:bottom="0dp" />
</shape>
```